# Cómo aplico Timeit en una función que tiene argumentos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer este ejercicio y al ejecutar el código me da error en la funcion `t.timeit`, primero me dice que debo poner un argumento para `random_matrix`, pero cuando lo pongo me dice que no está definido. ¿Alguna sugerencia? ¡Muchas gracias!

Pongo el ejercicio y lo que llevo realizado:

> compare los tiempos de ejecucion de cada una para realizar la suma de una matriz aleatoria con un escalar para matrices `10x10`, `1.000x1.000`, `10.000x10.000`.

```
#matriz 10x10

import timeit as t

import numpy

def random_matrix(s):

    random_matrix = numpy.random.random((10, 10))

    print(random_matrix)

    #defino scalar

    b = s

    C = random_matrix + b

    print(C)

random_matrix(2)

execution_time = t.timeit(random_matrix(), number=1)

print(execution_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tus errores son los siguientes:

1. La función `timeit` necesita que le pases el primer argumento como un `str`, es decir, debes de poner el nombre de la función en `str`
2. La función que tu has creado necesita que se le pase el parámetro `s`, y no le estás pasando ningún parámetro
3. La función `timeit` necesita que le indiques, dónde puede encontrar la función que quieres calcular su tiempo.

Para solucionar tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
import timeit as t
import numpy

def random_matrix(s):
    random_matrix = numpy.random.random((10, 10))
    print(random_matrix)
    #defino scalar
    b = s
    C = random_matrix + b
    print(C)

#Esta linea es la que cambiamos
execution_time = t.timeit("random_matrix(2)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print(execution_time)
```

**Salida:** `0.0038844099999550963`

- Hemos solucionado los dos primeros fallos pasandole el nombre de la función como `str` y el argumento `s`. `"random_matrix(2)"`
- `globals()` es una función de Python que nos devuelve todas las variables globales que existen, como has definido la función `random_matrix`, esta se encuentran en las variables globales, por tanto le indicamos a `timeit` **que vaya allí a buscar la función**. De esta forma solucionamos el tercer error

### Bonus

La librería `timeit` forma parte de la STL de Python, por lo que puedes encontrar documentación de calidad con ejemplos para aprender en la [página oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)